# Drupal adding a blank stylesheet?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

A Drupal site I'm working on seems to be adding a stylesheet which is breaking jQuery. 
This is an out of the box installation with no other modules added.

It's adding a href with an ampersand inside. I've looked through my entire theme, and cannot find this whatsoeve. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried flushing the cache ?!

Comment: Which theme are you using? Paste the .info file here, that might explain the issue.